# Nexus 3.4.0-02-win64

Tags: sonatype, nexus3

I try to install nexus 3.4.0-02-win64, but at the end exception is at the below occured, how can i resolve this issue?

I run "nexus.exe /run" command from directory .. "nexus-3.4.0-02-win64\nexus-3.4.0-02\bin>"
I have `java 8` on my pc , and it is `windows-64`.

> 2017-08-08 11:49:47,125+0300 ERROR [_shutdown_waiter] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>   2017-08-08 11:49:47,129+0300 ERROR [_shutdown_waiter] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>   2017-08-08 11:49:47,131+0300 ERROR [_shutdown_waiter] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>   2017-08-08 11:49:47,134+0300 ERROR [_shutdown_waiter] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>   2017-08-08 11:49:47,137+0300 ERROR [_shutdown_waiter] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -     at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher$1.run(WinLauncher.java:80)

Comment: It is not possible to tell you what the exact problem is from this log snippet, a complete log would be needed. But it seems clear there is an error in one of our configuration files, something that is supposed to be an integer value is not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a point in the operation where the command window seems to be reading user input to trigger application shutdown. If I hit the enter key, then it triggers this error. If I just ignore the command window, then the application runs. And if I try typing in a number and then hitting enter, Nexus shuts itself down but does not issue any error messages.